# does the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n-\ln n\rfloor}}{n}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

if we consider the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor| n-\ln n |\rfloor}}{n}}.$

It seems like an example of Leibniz, but here we have ${\lfloor | n-\ln n |\rfloor}$ which is annoying, how can we prove if it is convergent or divergent?

Comment: It might be treated similarly as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080849/is-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac-1-lfloor-sqrtn-rfloor-lnn-co?rq=1

Comment: yes, but here the problem here is $|ln(n)-n|$

Comment: Do you know the proof of Dirichlet's criterion?

Comment: yes, using abel's transformation (summation by parts)

Comment: Then you'll know that the boundedness of the partial sums is a stronger condition than needed. Here, look at the order of growth of $$\sum_{n = 1}^N (-1)^{\lfloor n - \ln n\rfloor}.$$

Comment: inside the floor there is absolute $|n-ln(n)|,$ or it doesn't have any sense, shouldn't we study the parity of $⌊|n−ln(n)|⌋$

Comment: @ronmacguire Why should there be absolute value, is there any $n>1$ such that $n-ln(n)<0$

Comment: Since $n > \ln n$ for all positive integers, the absolute value is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is equal to
$$
\sum_{k=0}(-1)^k\sum_{e^{k-1}\lt n\le e^k}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\tag{1}
$$
By the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test),
$$
\left|\,\sum_{e^{k-1}\lt n\le e^k}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\,\right|\le e^{1-k}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, by [Comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), the outer alternating sum in $(1)$ converges absolutely.